# Display Posts Only with Specific Tag

Tags: loop, tags

I'm trying to only display posts with the tags `Movie Trailers` and `Gaming Trailers` but my loops are still displaying everything under the category /videos/

heres what I have

category-videos.php:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php  ?>
<?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_gaming_trailers' ); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
get_template_part( 'content-videos', get_post_format() );
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and in the functions.php i have:

```
//Display Movie Trailers
function display_movie_trailers( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'movie trailers' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_movie-trailers' );

//Display Gaming Trailers
function display_gaming_trailers( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'gaming trailers' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_gaming-trailers' );
```

I made some mistakes in the `functions.php` code above, and corrected them with the code you suggested but nothing is appearing in the loop. The category is `videos` so I now have:

```
//Display Gaming Trailers
function display_gaming_trailers( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'videos') {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'gaming trailers' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_gaming_trailers' );
```

**Edit:** i tried `gaming trailers and the slug`gaming-trailers` without any luck.. anything that could be stopping this from working?

Comment: I'd check to make sure whether or not your tag slugs have spaces in them or not because they shouldn't.  `game trailers` probably should be `game-trailers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template, the `add_action` you have there is way too late because by the time WordPress gets to your template, the query has already been performed.

If this is for a category page, I'd do the following in your `functions.php`:

```
//Display Gaming Trailers
function display_gaming_trailers( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'video') {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'gaming-trailers' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_gaming_trailers' );
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I made some edits to the main post since my category is `videos` and my `add_action` was `display_gaming-trailers` instead of `display_gaming_trailers` so i corrected that also.  For some reason the loop is returning "Nothing Found
It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help."

Comment: Do you know the tag slug?

Comment: somehow the tags got removed from all the posts but after adding them its working fine! thanks!